# Toast inside thread during heavy workload task

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, toast

I am updating a database (SQLite) with a lot of data, which takes several minutes. I am doing this on a Thread. At the same time I want to show the progression of the updates (25%, 50%, etc.) through a Toast. Since I am within a thread, I need to use the runOnUiThread() function to run the Toast. Like this:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Updating the database...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

It was working fine when the workload was not to big. Now that it is, no toast is being displayed at all.

I have been looking for ways to set a very high priority to the toast's thread, without success. Maybe I can bypass using a thread for the toast in the first place?

Thank you for the insights!

***EDIT:*** In fact, the toast *is* working, but is displayed after all the work has been done. I want to notify the percentage of the complete update to the user, so I need to have the toast displayed during the update and not after.

I tried removing the workload (no database update, only a Log.d inside the for loop of things to add to the database). And the toast are displayed after the loop is finished although the `runOnUiThread()` method is called inside the loop.

***EDIT 2:*** I managed to do what I wanted after cleaning up the code and starting fresh. I posted the code I used as the answer below.

Comment: Do some parts of the big workload are performed on the main thread?

Comment: No, nothing is really happening on the main thread at this moment (only listening to button clicks, and so on). But because of the heavy workload, those are not responding either.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on the run function and make sure you're getting there?  Or on the runOnUIThread call?

Comment: Yes, and it goes to the run function. I update my question with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having cleaned up the initial thread, I managed to have something working. I post the code here since it can be used as a template to do a specific task:

Run a initial thread that does tasks periodically for a given number of times (here collect some data). After this given number of times, the collected data is pushed to a database and the user is notified of the advancement of the process (which takes a long time).

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
    long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - t0 > EXPERIMENT_DURATION ){
            processData(dataArrayList); // custom tasks - see below
            cancel();
        }else {
            dataArrayList = collectData(); // custom tasks
        }
    }
}, 0, INTERVAL);
```

With:

```
void processData(Arraylist<Data> dataArrayList){
    for(Data data : dataArrayList){
        // show progression to the user
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int percent = Math.round(((float)dataArrayList.indexOf(data))/((float)dataArrayList.size())*100)
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Update: " + Integer.toString(percent) + "%", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        updateDataBase(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

<del>I highly recommend you use an `AsyncTask`.</del>

<del>`AsyncTask` performs in another working `Thread`, but it offers a method that  is executed in the UI `Thread`, `publishProgress(String ...)`. that you then customize by overwriting `onProgressUpdate(String ...)`.</del>

**EDIT:** As read in the comments, `AsyncTask` is not that good of an option because:

- All AsyncTask share a `Thread` (they don't run on `workers` as I expected)
- For long running `Task`s, all other `AsyncTasks` (system's and your's) will be on hold
- This includes `AsyncTask`s from libraries

Comment: AsyncTasks should not be used on anything that goes more than a second or two.  The reason why is that all AsyncTasks share a common thread, and a long running task will starve any other AsyncTasks, since they cannot run until yours completes.  You can force parallelism via executeOnExecutor, but only so much.

Comment: @GabeSechan Really interesting, I thought they were just `workers`. I probably wouldn't have answered if I knew it, however, what's the problem if only one AsyncTask is working at a time?

Comment: If you have others pending, they starve. They won't be run until the previous ones are done. This includes any used by libraries you include, or in other activities. Best to avoid them for things that aren't short. They used to be pure workers in 2.x, Google changes them because a lot of android programmers didn't really know how to do parallel programming and caused race conditions

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks for clarification. I updated the answer accordingly. You look to be an experienced programmer in the Android field, could you suggest me some Android books? I am interested in the Android system (threads, services, workers, events etc.) and Material Design (scene, animated vector drawables etc). Just bought Big Nerd Ranch 3rd edition Introductory book, but I am finding it too simple, since I have been programming in Android for 16 months. Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, not really.  I've learned more by diving in and getting my hands dirty than by books, I haven't read enough of them to give good suggestions.

Comment: The documentation definitely says it " performs the blocking operations in a worker thread" so is it that they all share the same worker thread then?